# Plus instead of a space in the url

Tags: python, url, utf-8, request, ascii

I'm getting a string url request, I want to handle it and send the parameters, because it is very long.
I get plus in `req.url` instead of a space like `query`.

```
query = "https://www.superjob.ru/resume/search_resume.html?sbmit=1&detail_search=1&keywords%5B0%5D%5Bkeys%5D=%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0&keywords%5B0%5D%5Bskwc%5D=or&keywords%5B0%5D%5Bsrws%5D=60&keywords%5B1%5D%5Bkeys%5D=%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0&keywords%5B1%5D%5Bskwc%5D=or&keywords%5B1%5D%5Bsrws%5D=7&keywords%5B2%5D%5Bkeys%5D=%D0%AE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82&keywords%5B2%5D%5Bskwc%5D=nein&keywords%5B2%5D%5Bsrws%5D=50&keywords%5B3%5D%5Bkeys%5D=%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C+%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82+%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82+%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B2*&keywords%5B3%5D%5Bskwc%5D=nein&keywords%5B3%5D%5Bsrws%5D=60&exclude_words=%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C+%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82+%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82+%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B2*&period=7&place_of_work=0&t%5B%5D=4&m%5B%5D=194&m%5B%5D=195&m%5B%5D=193&m%5B%5D=192&m%5B%5D=191&m%5B%5D=164&m%5B%5D=162&m%5B%5D=163&m%5B%5D=150&m%5B%5D=534&m%5B%5D=540&m%5B%5D=149&m%5B%5D=148&m%5B%5D=147&m%5B%5D=146&m%5B%5D=535&m%5B%5D=536&m%5B%5D=159&m%5B%5D=157&m%5B%5D=158&m%5B%5D=156&m%5B%5D=155&m%5B%5D=154&m%5B%5D=161&m%5B%5D=20&m%5B%5D=21&m%5B%5D=22&m%5B%5D=24&m%5B%5D=23&m%5B%5D=25&m%5B%5D=28&m%5B%5D=573&m%5B%5D=29&m%5B%5D=27&m%5B%5D=26&m%5B%5D=145&m%5B%5D=144&m%5B%5D=143&m%5B%5D=142&m%5B%5D=141&m%5B%5D=30&m%5B%5D=31&m%5B%5D=115&m%5B%5D=153&m%5B%5D=72&m%5B%5D=84&m%5B%5D=152&m%5B%5D=83&m%5B%5D=82&m%5B%5D=81&m%5B%5D=79&m%5B%5D=80&m%5B%5D=542&m%5B%5D=151&m%5B%5D=46&m%5B%5D=85&paymentfrom=20000&paymentto=35000&type_of_work=0&citizenship%5B0%5D=1&old1=18&old2=40&maritalstatus=0&pol=0&children=0&education=0&eduform=0&id_institute=0&institution=&languages%5B0%5D%5Blanguage_id%5D=0&languages%5B0%5D%5Blanguage_level%5D=0&business_trip=0"
def getparams(url):
    params = {}
    urlarr = url.split("&")
    i = 0
    while i < len(urlarr):
        params[urllib2.unquote(urlarr[i].split("=")[0].encode("utf-8"))] = urllib2.unquote(urlarr[i].split("=")[1].encode('utf-8'))
        i += 1
    return params
s = Session()
req = s.get(query.split("?")[0], params=getparams(query.split("?")[1]))
print(req.url)
```

I tried `decode()` instead `encode()` and without `encode()` and without `urllib2.unquote()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem like this:

```
query = "https://www.superjob.ru/resume/search_resume.html?sbmit=1&detail_search=1&keywords%5B0%5D%5Bkeys%5D=%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0&keywords%5B0%5D%5Bskwc%5D=or&keywords%5B0%5D%5Bsrws%5D=60&keywords%5B1%5D%5Bkeys%5D=%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0&keywords%5B1%5D%5Bskwc%5D=or&keywords%5B1%5D%5Bsrws%5D=7&keywords%5B2%5D%5Bkeys%5D=%D0%AE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82&keywords%5B2%5D%5Bskwc%5D=nein&keywords%5B2%5D%5Bsrws%5D=50&keywords%5B3%5D%5Bkeys%5D=%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C+%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82+%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82+%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B2*&keywords%5B3%5D%5Bskwc%5D=nein&keywords%5B3%5D%5Bsrws%5D=60&exclude_words=%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C+%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82+%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82+%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B2*&period=7&place_of_work=0&t%5B%5D=4&m%5B%5D=194&m%5B%5D=195&m%5B%5D=193&m%5B%5D=192&m%5B%5D=191&m%5B%5D=164&m%5B%5D=162&m%5B%5D=163&m%5B%5D=150&m%5B%5D=534&m%5B%5D=540&m%5B%5D=149&m%5B%5D=148&m%5B%5D=147&m%5B%5D=146&m%5B%5D=535&m%5B%5D=536&m%5B%5D=159&m%5B%5D=157&m%5B%5D=158&m%5B%5D=156&m%5B%5D=155&m%5B%5D=154&m%5B%5D=161&m%5B%5D=20&m%5B%5D=21&m%5B%5D=22&m%5B%5D=24&m%5B%5D=23&m%5B%5D=25&m%5B%5D=28&m%5B%5D=573&m%5B%5D=29&m%5B%5D=27&m%5B%5D=26&m%5B%5D=145&m%5B%5D=144&m%5B%5D=143&m%5B%5D=142&m%5B%5D=141&m%5B%5D=30&m%5B%5D=31&m%5B%5D=115&m%5B%5D=153&m%5B%5D=72&m%5B%5D=84&m%5B%5D=152&m%5B%5D=83&m%5B%5D=82&m%5B%5D=81&m%5B%5D=79&m%5B%5D=80&m%5B%5D=542&m%5B%5D=151&m%5B%5D=46&m%5B%5D=85&paymentfrom=20000&paymentto=35000&type_of_work=0&citizenship%5B0%5D=1&old1=18&old2=40&maritalstatus=0&pol=0&children=0&education=0&eduform=0&id_institute=0&institution=&languages%5B0%5D%5Blanguage_id%5D=0&languages%5B0%5D%5Blanguage_level%5D=0&business_trip=0"
query = query.encode('utf-8')
s = Session()
req = s.get(query.split("?")[0], params=parse_qs(urlparse(query).query))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the url you are posting?
 you set

```
query = "https://www.superjob.ru/resume/search_resume.html?sbmit=1&detail_search=1&keywords%5B0%5D%5Bkeys%5D=%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0&keywords%5B0%5D%5Bskwc%5D=or&keywords%5B0%5D%5Bsrws%5D=60&keywords%5B1%5D%5Bkeys%5D=%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0&keywords%5B1%5D%5Bskwc%5D=or&keywords%5B1%5D%5Bsrws%5D=7&keywords%5B2%5D%5Bkeys%5D=%D0%AE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82&keywords%5B2%5D%5Bskwc%5D=nein&keywords%5B2%5D%5Bsrws%5D=50&keywords%5B3%5D%5Bkeys%5D=%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C+%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82+%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82+%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B2*&keywords%5B3%5D%5Bskwc%5D=nein&keywords%5B3%5D%5Bsrws%5D=60&exclude_words=%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C+%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82+%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82+%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B2*&period=7&place_of_work=0&t%5B%5D=4&m%5B%5D=194&m%5B%5D=195&m%5B%5D=193&m%5B%5D=192&m%5B%5D=191&m%5B%5D=164&m%5B%5D=162&m%5B%5D=163&m%5B%5D=150&m%5B%5D=534&m%5B%5D=540&m%5B%5D=149&m%5B%5D=148&m%5B%5D=147&m%5B%5D=146&m%5B%5D=535&m%5B%5D=536&m%5B%5D=159&m%5B%5D=157&m%5B%5D=158&m%5B%5D=156&m%5B%5D=155&m%5B%5D=154&m%5B%5D=161&m%5B%5D=20&m%5B%5D=21&m%5B%5D=22&m%5B%5D=24&m%5B%5D=23&m%5B%5D=25&m%5B%5D=28&m%5B%5D=573&m%5B%5D=29&m%5B%5D=27&m%5B%5D=26&m%5B%5D=145&m%5B%5D=144&m%5B%5D=143&m%5B%5D=142&m%5B%5D=141&m%5B%5D=30&m%5B%5D=31&m%5B%5D=115&m%5B%5D=153&m%5B%5D=72&m%5B%5D=84&m%5B%5D=152&m%5B%5D=83&m%5B%5D=82&m%5B%5D=81&m%5B%5D=79&m%5B%5D=80&m%5B%5D=542&m%5B%5D=151&m%5B%5D=46&m%5B%5D=85&paymentfrom=20000&paymentto=35000&type_of_work=0&citizenship%5B0%5D=1&old1=18&old2=40&maritalstatus=0&pol=0&children=0&education=0&eduform=0&id_institute=0&institution=&languages%5B0%5D%5Blanguage_id%5D=0&languages%5B0%5D%5Blanguage_level%5D=0&business_trip=0"
```

which contains a lot of escape quotes. None of them are a space (`%20`)

The reason you get a plus instead of a space, is because your url contains a plus in place of every space. This is expected behaviour, as proper URLs should not contain any spaces, and thus, are often converted into "+" beforehand.

If I put your escaped URL into my browser hotbar and look at it, all I see is "+", no spaces there.

This is from somewhere at the start of your URL:

```
detail_search=1&keywords%5B0%5D%5Bkeys%5D=%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA
```

which is essentially `detail_search=1&keywords[0][keys]=Кладовщик+Комплектовщик`
if unescaped. As you can clearly see, both versions, quoted and unquoted, contain the plus. This is done by the website, and can't (shouldn't) be changed, especially if you want to reconstruct the URL somewhere else.

If you need the parameters without the plus, just do `"myUnquotedString".replace("+"," ")` (after unquoting, because i don't know what urllib2 does if it gets a malformed string as parameter for `unquote()`.